/tf out of sync
My tf_tree looks like this above. The transforms that happen through /joint_states. I assume that the robot control's pc clock is not synced with my pc. Because of that, if I push a transform based on lets say 'realsense_cam', the TF cannot be shown in RViz b/c No transform from my_frame to world can be found.
I'm using a ros parameter bridge to bridge the topic /joint_states from ros1 to ros2.
The problem is, I'm having no access to that embedded pc (inside the robot control) and this is the one launching roscore and running the hardware node (which publishes to /joint_states I guess).
So right now I cannot use rviz to visualize my transforms. Are there any work arounds?
Thanks
EDIT: Here my code of custom state publisher:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("lara_state_publisher_node")

    while True:
        try:
            self.robot = Robot()
            break
        except Exception:
            continue

    self.pub = self.create_publisher(JointState, "/joint_states", 11)
    self.timer = self.create_timer(0.01, self.timer_callback)
    self.get_logger().info("Finished initialization.")

def timer_callback(self):
    cur_angles = self.robot.get_current_joint_angles()
    msg = JointState()
    msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
    msg.name = self.joint_names
    msg.position = cur_angles
    msg.effort = self.joint_efforts
    self.pub.publish(msg)
    self.get_logger().info("published joint states.")

I don't get why there are different timings. RobotStatePublisher is the one responsible for publishing the transforms based on the urdf, right?


How far off are you clocks? If you're not synchronized, you're asking unanswerable questions of the system. It knows about the world at time t, and you're asking about things at time t2. It doesn't know how things have evolved before or after it's data.

There are some other things that might be at issue, to get better help please reduce your problem down to a minimum reproduction so that we can know exactly what your problem is and help you fix it.

So, I don't have any access to the robot control what-so-ever.

OK, So I tried around.
I've written my own publisher that publishes to /joint_states with 100Hz frequency and disabled the rosbridge.
The transforms are there, I can see the robot model in rviz. Problem is that the tf tree still looks like like this one above. See the code of the custom publisher cb in the edited question.

Your transform tree looks like everything is either at the single timestamp, or is a static transform. There shouldn't be a problem with the lookup in that tree. Can you share an example of how to reproduce your lookup error including the exact error message(s)?

OP you said, "No transform from my_frame to world can be found," and I don't see my_frame in the tf tree. Can you echo realsense_cam to world? What is publishing the my_frame frame?
